# How to prove that $df_x$ is well defined with respect to different chart $\psi^{\prime}_{V^{\prime}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, self-learning, equivalence-relations, tangent-spaces

I am studying Moroianu book lectures on Kähler geometry. I am  trying to show that the map $df_x$ is well defined. Choose charts $\phi^{\prime}_{U^{\prime}}$ and $\psi^{\prime}_{V^{\prime}}$ around x and f(x). It follows that $[U,u] = [U^{\prime},u^{\prime}]$ and $[V,v] = [V^{\prime},v^{\prime}]$. It follows
$$u = d\phi_{{UU^{\prime}}_{\phi_U^{\prime}(x)}} (u^{\prime})$$
$$v  = d\psi_{{VV^{\prime}}_{\psi_V^{\prime}(x)}} (v^{\prime})$$
Therefore
$df([U,x]) = 
[V,d(\psi_V \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}(U) \circ d\phi_{{UU^{\prime}}_{\phi_U^{\prime}(x)}} (u^{\prime})] = [V, d(\psi_V \circ f \circ \phi_U^{\prime})x]$

I am missing $\psi_V^{\prime}$. I am not sure how to get rid of $\psi_V$? In order to show well-definedness.
[image]

Comment: To change from $V$ to $V^\prime$ you need to postcompose the map $\mathrm{d}\Phi_{VV^\prime}$. How can you artificially make this map appear? (You subsequently need to use the chain rule)

Comment: @SvenPistre can you add an answer and I will accept it. I am confused on how this map appears. I have written up my work in the question above.

Comment: @SvenPistre when you postcompose you change the whole function I am also confused by this.

Comment: @SvenPistre : Edited: I think I see it if you postcompose with $\psi_{V^{\prime}V}$. By the Chain rule we have $d(\psi_{V^{\prime}V} \circ \psi_V \circ f \circ \phi_U) = d(\psi_{V^{\prime}} \circ f \circ \phi_U)$ right?

Comment: The standard trick to make (invertible) maps appear is to use $\mathrm{Id}=A^{-1}\circ A$.You’re last comment seems correct but you still need to use the equivalence relation to finish. There are a few typos (?) in your calculation above. I’ll write an answer later when I have some time.

Comment: @SvenPistre Thank you so much. I have been stuck in this for sometime. I will wait for the answer when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my comment, you have by definition
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}f_x([U,u]) = [V, \mathrm{d}(\psi_{V}\circ f \circ \phi_{U}^{-1})_{\phi_U(x)}(u)]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The definition of tangent vectors as equivalence classes means that for tangent vectors at $x\in M$
$$
\begin{align}
  [U^{\prime},u^{\prime}]=[U,\mathrm{d}(\phi_{UU^{\prime}})_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})] \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and for tangent vectors at $f(x)\in N$
$$
\begin{align}
  [V^{\prime},v^{\prime}]=[V,\mathrm{d}(\psi_{VV^{\prime}})_{\psi_{V^{\prime}}(f(x))}(v^{\prime})] \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi_{U^{\prime}U}=\phi_{U^{\prime}}\circ \phi_{U}^{-1}$ and $\psi_{V^{\prime}V}=\psi_{V^{\prime}}\circ \psi_{V}^{-1}$ are the transition maps between two charts around $x\in M$ and $f(x)\in N$.

Carefully unraveling all the definitions you now get
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{d}f_x([U^{\prime},u^{\prime}]) 
        &= \mathrm{d}f_x\big([U,\mathrm{d}(\phi_{UU^{\prime}})_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})]\big)  \\
        &= \big[V, \mathrm{d}(\psi_{V}\circ f \circ \phi_{U}^{-1})_{\phi_{U}(x)}\circ \mathrm{d}(\phi_{UU^{\prime}})_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})\big]  \\
        &= \big[V, \mathrm{d}\big(\psi_{V}\circ f \circ \phi_{U}^{-1} \circ \phi_{UU^{\prime}}\big)_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})\big]  \\
        &= \big[V, \mathrm{d}\big(\psi_{V} \circ \psi_{V^{\prime}}^{-1} \circ \psi_{V^{\prime}} \circ f \circ \phi_{U}^{-1} \circ \phi_{U} \circ \phi_{U^{\prime}}^{-1}\big)_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})\big]  \\
        &= \big[V, \mathrm{d}(\psi_{VV^{\prime}})_{\psi_{V^{\prime}}(f(x))} \Big(\mathrm{d}\big(\psi_{V^{\prime}} \circ f \circ \phi_{U^{\prime}}^{-1}\big)_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})\Big)\big]  \\
        &= \big[V^{\prime}, \mathrm{d}\big(\psi_{V^{\prime}} \circ f \circ \phi_{U^{\prime}}^{-1}\big)_{\phi_{U^{\prime}}(x)}(u^{\prime})\big]
\end{align}
$$
where we used in order of appearance eq. (2), eq. (1), chain rule, definition of transition maps, chain rule, eq. (3).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!